# GeoServer WMS request performance: Layer Group vs Layer List

Tags: geoserver, wms, group-layer

Let's say there are few transparent raster layers A, B, C...

I would imagine that it is better (performance wise) **a)** to have these layers marked as non-cacheable then create a layer group from them and cache it than **b)** having each layer cached and making WMS requests where list of layers is provided as LAYERS parameter, e.g., http://....&LAYERS=A,B,C....&STYLEs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes a layer group would be best, I'm pretty sure that making a request for multiple layers defeats the cache and you lose all benefit to it. The alternative to a layer group that would be almost as fast is to make 3 (or more) requests for each layer separately - this would use more bandwidth though.

Comment: Also does having A, B, C layers cached separately and creating a layer group from them means that layer group does not have to be cached for the layer group to be served as cached layer? Do WMS requests for this layer group will return HIT in the header?

Comment: I don't think so, but you'd need to check the code to be sure